# I can't get access to static properties or fields of my generic base class in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

This is the code of my base class:

```
namespace Business;

public abstract class Business<ReadModel, WriteModel> : ReadBusiness<ReadModel>
    where ReadModel : class, IEntity, new()
    where WriteModel : class, IEntity, new()
{
    protected abstract Write<WriteModel> Write { get; }

    public static List<Action<WriteModel>> PreCreationAugmenters = new List<Action<WriteModel>>();

    public static List<Action<WriteModel>> PostCreationAugmenters = new List<Action<WriteModel>>();

    public static List<Action<WriteModel>> PreUpdateAugmenters = new List<Action<WriteModel>>();
```

And this is my derived class:

```
namespace Taxonomy;

public class TagBusiness : Business<TagView, Tag>
{
```

And now I want to access the `PostCreationAugmenters` of the base class from `typeof(TagBusiness)`.

I tried:

```
typeof(TagBusiness).GetProperty("PostCreationAugmenters", BindingFlags.Static); // null
typeof(TagBusiness).GetField("PostCreationAugmenters", BindingFlags.Static); //null
typeof(TagBusiness).BaseType.GetProperty("PostCreationAugmenters"); // null
```

I want to get access to that list, and add an augmenter to it.

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: Why do you need to use reflection in the first place? Why not simply whrite `PostCreationAugmenters`? But if you insist: 1) this is a field, not a property, so use GetField and 2) it is defined in a base class, so you need to add `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy`

Comment: @KlausGütter I have to use reflection because those Business classes are loaded from many DLL files dynamically. What do you mean by *simply write*? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Example: `TagBusiness.PostCreationAugmenters`, or `Business<TagView, Tag>.PostCreationAugmenters` . In your code, you wrote `typeof(TagBusiness).GetField(...` so it seems the type `TagBusiness` is available at this point.

Comment: @KlausGütter that's my bad. That `TagBusiness` is the string of the type to be instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with all comments @Klaus provided with a small "correction": more binding flags have to be specified

```
typeof(TagBusiness).GetField(
    "PostCreationAugmenters", 
    BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy 
        | BindingFlags.Public 
        | BindingFlags.Static
);
```